# What does the "View as render" option in the background image settings do?

Tags: interface, 3d-view, image

What does the *View as render* option in the 3D view background image settings do?  The [Blender wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/3D_View_Options#Background_Image) does not mention it, and I have not been able to find anything about it.
[image]

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://gitorious.org/blenderprojects/fullblender/commit/b0e8a0860d097ec11bf78a11bc11139fcfb0287a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does nothing for the background image in the 3D view. However *View as render* is a setting for the entire image datablock.
What *View as render* does do in the compositer and image viewer is toggle on or off the *Color Management* settings in the properties window.

With *View as render* off   <sub>click for full size</sub>
[image: off]

With *View as render* on    <sub>click for full size</sub>
[image: on]

Comment: Hm.. So it seems that the setting isn't supposed to be visible (and using valuable space) in the background image section? (Sounds like this is a bug)

Comment: @gandalf3 yes I don't see any reason for it to be there.